# Upgrading Zerigo DNS plan through Heroku failure

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record, heroku, zerigo

I'm hosting an app on Heroku and have a basic DNS plan with Zerigo. I tried to upgrade the Zerigo plan from "basic" to "tier 1" through the Heroku command line tool and received the following error:

- Hostname may not be assigned to both a CNAME and other record types
  at the same time (the CNAME would override all other record types
  with the same hostname anyway)

Can anyone help me understand this error message, or has anyone experienced this issue firsthand?

**Update:**

I had no duplicate CNAME entries and I was able to upgrade my account directly through the Zerigo site. See my comment to the accepted answer below. I'll add another update if/when Zerigo or Heroku confirms the root cause.

Comment: This issue still exists to this day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you create a CNAME record entry you may not then create another record with the same name.

See RFC 1034, section 3.6.2.

"If a CNAME RR is present at a node, no other data should be
present; this ensures that the data for a canonical name and its aliases
cannot be different.  This rule also insures that a cached CNAME can be
used without checking with an authoritative server for other RR types."

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1034.txt

Comment: I checked and didn't have a duplicate CNAME entry. I was able to upgrade my account directly through Zerigo, so it appears to be a bug in either the Zerigo API or Heroku CLI. Accepting your answer, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This is a known issue with the Heroku Zerigo integration. The best thing to do if you encounter this is to transfer your Heroku Zerigo account to a [Zerigo direct account](https://www.zerigo.com/managed-dns/pricing#dns-free).

Fortunately Zerigo provides a domain reassignment function which allows you to migrate your domain between accounts with zero downtime or hassle. You can find the domain reassignment function under DNS -> Domains -> (your domain) -> Tools -> Reassign Domain in the Heroku Zerigo add-on.

If you have trouble locating the domain reassign function, check out this [screenshot](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2968534/Screenshots/Zerigo/GenerateReassignmentToken.png).